# what is the framework using in Blender GUI?

Tags: frameworks, blender

What is the framework using in Blender GUI?
QT? Or Tk, GTK+, FOX toolkit, wxWidgets?
Because Blender is cross-platform application.

Comment: Also note that if you ask because you want to add some dialog you can use bgui for that: http://code.google.com/p/bgui/wiki/Gallery

Comment: While Blender UI is not separable from Blender itself and thus not usable in your own project, you might be interested by https://github.com/zhanggyb/BlendInt which is a GUI library designed with Blender UI as main inspiration

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Blender uses [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/) to draw all of its user interface. (Personally I'm a fan!)

Comment: And there is no library for that GUI widgets, which could be used in other projects too?

Comment: Correct, @KarlZeilhofer. See this thread for confirmation
https://devtalk.blender.org/t/using-the-node-editor-in-a-private-project/8103

Answer (score 11):

Blender's interface is entirely custom

Answer (score 5):

None of those, apparently. I come to this conclusion from the fact that the Debian-packaged Blender doesn't depend on any GUI toolkit, and based on the threads at the Blender forum [here](http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14357&sid=b842ad74b03cb7e70bdd98a559714973) and [here](http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=57840&highlight=&sid=643e3e8480b6862f1ec37d0dab11a95a). Note the phrase in the second thread:

> There is probably zero (or at least
>   quite little) chance of QT or GTK or
>   any other rather heavy gui toolkit
>   being used with Blender.